# Why should I use facades in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I don't quite understand why should I use facades in Laravel. Why don't just create simple class with static methods instead? I mean, these methods I can call from almost any place in my code just like using Facades. That way I don't need to create facade, add it to autoload section in composer.json or bind it in ServiceProvider. What I see is the same result using both options, but using facades is much more complicated way to me.

Answer (score 3):

They are described in details [here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades)

From my experience, the biggest benefit of a Facade is the ability to mock or stub the methods it contains, which is not possibile (or at least is very hard) to do with a purely static class.

So, basically, Facades are easier to test.